# Generalizing CRUD tests in Linq to Entities

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities

We have a lot of tests such as this:

```
using (new TransactionScope())
{
    var repository = _unitOfWork.DataFieldSetRepository;

    var entity = new DataFieldSet {Label = "test", Title = "test"};

    repository.Add(entity);
    _unitOfWork.Commit();

    entity = repository.GetAll().Single(x => x.Id == entity.Id);

    entity.IsClosed = true;
    repository.Update(entity);
    _unitOfWork.Commit();

    repository.Delete(entity);
    _unitOfWork.Commit();
}
```

There are no Asserts because the test is passed unless an exception is thrown.

Instead of copying this code and altering a few details, I would like to generalize it.
The only bits that vary are

1) The entity type and the corresponding repository (here DataFieldSet and DataFieldSetRepository)
2) The contents of the newly created entity (typically the minimal contents to make the test pass, here Label and Title cannot be null)
3) The update operation (typically just one random property has its value changed)

So far I have this:

```
public void AssertCrudOperationsWork<T>(T entity, Func<T, T, bool> keyComparer, Action<T> updateAction) where T : class
{
    using (new TransactionScope())
    {
        var repository = (IRepository<T>)_unitOfWork.GetType().GetProperty(typeof(T).Name + "Repository").GetValue(_unitOfWork);

        repository.Add(entity);
        _unitOfWork.Commit();

        //var keyProperties = typeof(T).GetProperties().Where(prop => prop.IsDefined(typeof(KeyAttribute), false));

        Expression<Func<T, bool>> keyEqualsKey = x => keyComparer(x, entity);
        entity = repository.GetAll().Single(keyEqualsKey);

        updateAction(entity);
        repository.Update(entity);
        _unitOfWork.Commit();

        repository.Delete(entity);
        _unitOfWork.Commit();
    }            
}

[TestMethod]
public void CRUDTest_DataFieldGroup()
{
    AssertCrudOperationsWork(new DataFieldSet {Label = "test", Title = "test"}, (a, b) => a.Id == b.Id, x => x.IsClosed = true);
}
```

The problem is, it fails in the call to `Single()` with: `The LINQ expression node type 'Invoke' is not supported in LINQ to Entities.`

I guess my `keyEqualsKey` predicate is not exactly the same as the original `x => x.Id == entity.Id`.

Is there a way to fix this?

The commented line `//var keyProperties ...` gets all the key properties of the entity. Is there a dynamic way to build the predicate comparing the entity keys so that the `keyComparer` and the `keyEqualsKey` can be removed altogether?

Comment: I'm fairly sure you need to change `Func<T, T, bool> keyComparer` in your parameter list into an expression, something like; `Expression<Func<T, T, bool>> keyComparer`

Comment: If I do that, the line `Expression<Func<T, bool>> keyEqualsKey = x => keyComparer(x, entity);` does not compile anymore. I tried changing it to `Expression<Func<T, bool>> keyEqualsKey = x => keyComparer.Invoke(x, entity);`. It then compiles, but throws an exception:

Comment: `LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Boolean Invoke[DataFieldSet,DataFieldSet,Boolean](System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1[System.Func`3[Traen.TAS.Domain.TAS.DataCalculation.DataFieldSet,Traen.TAS.Domain.TAS.DataCalculation.DataFieldSet,System.Boolean]], Traen.TAS.Domain.TAS.DataCalculation.DataFieldSet, Traen.TAS.Domain.TAS.DataCalculation.DataFieldSet)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.`